# Unique representation as a linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be an infinite dimensional vector space and $B$ be a basis. I would like to prove that every element of $V$ has a unique representation as a linear combination of elements of $B$.

I can visualize why this is true (heuristically: take the first representation minus the second and get linear dependence), however I seem unable to do the technical work. It is tricky. The finite dimensional case is trivial and it can't be generalized.

Can someone show me how to do this?

Comment: Assume it has two representations, then take the first one minus the second one you will get a linear dependece. The existence is by definition (if not how do you define a basis?)

Comment: There is no difference between the finite dimensional and the infinite dimensional cases; a linear combination is by definition a *finite* sum.

Comment: NO. It's **not** a duplicate and yes there is a technical difference between the two cases. Gee.

Comment: I don't understand.. Have I answered the question or should I do all the details?

Comment: @user426577 no. You didn't answer the question. If you'd like, yes, provide details please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definition: Let V be a vector base, then a set of vectors B is a basis if every $v\in V$ is a finite linear combination of elements in B and every finite subset of B is linearily independent.

Now assume by contradiction there exists two different representations

$$v=\sum_{i\in I_1} \beta_i b_i$$

$$v=\sum_{i\in I_2}^m \alpha_j b_i$$

Where $b_i$ are elements in B and $\alpha_i,\beta_i$ scalars, $I_1,I_2$ are finite sets of indexes.

Now take the first representation minus the second we have 
$$0=\sum_{i\in I_1-I_2} \beta_i b_i - \sum_{i\in I_2-I_1} \alpha_i b_i +\sum_{i\in I_1\cap I_2} (\beta_i-\alpha_i) b_i$$

This is a linear combination of 0 and therefore we have

1. For all $i\in I_1-I_2$ we have $\beta_i=0$
2. For all $i\in I_2-I_1$ we have $\alpha_i=0$
3. If $i\in I_1\cap I_2$ we have $\alpha_i=\beta_i$

It follows that the two representations above are the same representation.

Comment: That is still avoiding the technical work. The assumption on linear independence is: if $\sum_{i \in I} \alpha_i a_i =0$, for $I$ a finite set and $a_i \in B$, then $\alpha_i = 0$ for all $i$.

Comment: I want to know just how to go from $\sum_{i =1}^n \beta_i b_i - \sum_{j=1}^m \alpha_i a_i$ to an appropriate sum of the form $\sum_{i\in I} \gamma_i c_i$.

Comment: Now that I edit.. Do you understand?

Comment: Yep. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Let $\beta$ be a basis of a vector space $V$. Suppose
$$
\sum_{v\in \beta}a_v\cdot v=\sum_{v\in\beta}b_v\cdot v\tag{1}
$$
where all but finitely many $a_v$ and $b_v$ are zero. Equation (1) is equivalent to
$$
\sum_{v\in\beta}(a_v-b_v)\cdot v=\vec 0\tag{2}
$$
But $\beta$ is linearly independent since $\beta$ is a basis, so equation (2) implies that $a_v-b_v=0$ for each $v\in V$. Thus $a_v=b_v$ for each $v\in V$. This proves that the linear combinations in (1) are the same.

Comment: Are we allowed to do this? Writing $\sum_{v \in \beta} a_v v$?

Comment: Of course. The key statement here is: "where all but finitely many $a_v$ and $b_v$ are zero"

Comment: But is this rigorous? (I understand that all but finitely many are zero, but this approach makes me uneasy)

Comment: Do you understand the definition of span in an infinite-dimensional vector space?

Comment: Yes, perfectly well. Do you have something to say?

Comment: The definition of span in an infinite-dimensional vector space is exactly what guarantees that the sum you're worried about exists...

Comment: I am talking about a different thing. Just forget it..

Comment: What are you talking about?